# Scrapy with APscheduler only works half the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, apscheduler

I have the following code which only works every 2 hours rather than every hour. I have the data stored to MongoDb through pipeline and thus I see the id being to change by two rather than one and the same with time.

What the code intends to do is every hour scrape the number of people online in 100 subreddits saved in the data.csv file and push the data to mongoDb cloud server. Everything works fine except it only is able to scrape every two hours rather than every hour.

```
class SubredditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'subreddit'
    sub_list = [] # list of subreddits
    count = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        SubredditSpider.count += 1
        if SubredditSpider.count > 24:
            SubredditSpider.count = 1
        with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in csv_reader:
                self.sub_list.append(row[0])

        for sub in self.sub_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(f'https://www.reddit.com{sub}/about.json', self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        subreddit = data['data']['display_name']
        active_users = data['data']['active_user_count']

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
        current_date = now.strftime("%d:%m:%Y")

        yield {
            '_id': SubredditSpider.count,
            'subreddit': subreddit,
            'active_users': active_users,
            'time': current_time,
            'date': current_date
        }


def main():

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    scheduler = TwistedScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'cron', args=[
                      SubredditSpider], hour='*')
    scheduler.start()
    process.start(False)
```

The hour when it doesn't run has the log

```
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [apscheduler.scheduler] DEBUG: Looking for jobs to run
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [apscheduler.scheduler] DEBUG: Next wakeup is due at 2020-09-24 11:00:00+00:00 (in 3599.898356 seconds)
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [apscheduler.executors.default] INFO: Running job "CrawlerRunner.crawl (trigger: cron[hour='*'], next run at: 2020-09-24 11:00:00 UTC)" (scheduled at 2020-09-24 10:00:00+00:00)
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'reddit',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'reddit.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['reddit.spiders']}
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: telnet_password
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['reddit.pipelines.RedditPipeline']
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-24 10:00:00 [apscheduler.executors.default] INFO: Job "CrawlerRunner.crawl (trigger: cron[hour='*'], next run at: 2020-09-24 11:00:00 UTC)" executed successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to run the spider every minute and scrape 100 times the same URL and it worked for me, I let it ran for ever 10 minutes.

Also I tried with requests library and make a request every second, and everything worked

I googled for reddit api rate limits and some post said you can make 100 request but in their actual documentation they limit it to 60.

https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API

They allow you to scrape everything within the boundries on the link I share but you have to authenticate yourself.

My only theory is that they block your second scrape due to exceding their hour rates, maybe you can try with proxies or authenticating.

Also if you want you can sahre me your URL list and I can re run my test. Maybe I am not exceding their limits because I am requesting the same thing over and over.

```
import scrapy
import json
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class SubredditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'subreddit'
    sub_list = []  # list of subreddits
    count = 0
    custom_settings = {}

    def start_requests(self):
        SubredditSpider.count += 1
        if SubredditSpider.count > 24:
            SubredditSpider.count = 1
        for _ in range(100):
            yield scrapy.Request('https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/about.json', self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response, *args):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        subreddit = data['data']['display_name']
        active_users = data['data']['active_user_count']

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
        current_date = now.strftime("%d:%m:%Y")

        yield {
            '_id': SubredditSpider.count,
            'subreddit': subreddit,
            'active_users': active_users,
            'time': current_time,
            'date': current_date
        }


def main():
    process = CrawlerProcess({'BOT_NAME': 'reddit'})
    scheduler = TwistedScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'interval', args=[
        SubredditSpider], minutes=1)
    scheduler.start()
    process.start(False)


def get_active_users():
    url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/about.json"

    payload = {}
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.3',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        subreddit = data['data']['display_name']
        active_users = data['data']['active_user_count']

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
        current_date = now.strftime("%d:%m:%Y")

        print({
            '_id': SubredditSpider.count,
            'subreddit': subreddit,
            'active_users': active_users,
            'time': current_time,
            'date': current_date
        })
        SubredditSpider.count += 1
    else:
        print(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    # scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    # scheduler.add_job(get_active_users, 'interval', seconds=1)
    # scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying again. I re-run the code, apparently it doesn't run at the first trigger itself so it definitely is not a rate issue. And for URL I have none. I just have the data you need to append after reddit.com which is https://pastebin.com/mNgCrfWR. ALSO, I think there is a difference between 'cron' and 'interval'. I used 'cron' and I think with interval it worked fine for me too. But I wanted to use 'cron' because only that runs the program every hour sharp.